# How to fix 'cannot find -lgmp' build error on OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, omnet++, mingw-w64

I have become aware that OverSim can be used with the newer versions of OMNeT++. I installed OMNeT++ 5.6.1 on Windows 10 by following the instructions in InstallGuide. Then, I imported INET 3.6.5 in OMNeT++ and built it, there were no errors. Finally, I imported OverSim-20190424 and when I build it I get the following error at the end of the build process:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/omnet561/oversim-20190424/src'
Creating executable: ../out/gcc-debug/src/OverSim_dbg.exe
C:/omnet561/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmp
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:418: ../out/gcc-debug/src/OverSim_dbg.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/omnet561/oversim-20190424/src'
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug -j8 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

12:15:59 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 12s.448ms)
```

The other two errors are:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 2    OverSim         C/C++ Problem
make[1]: *** [Makefile:418: ../out/clang-debug/src/OverSim_dbg.exe] Error 1 OverSim         C/C++ Problem
```

Does anyone know how this error can be fixed? I have tried using OverSim on Windows 7 as well and tried using OMNeT++ 5.4.1 but the same error is still produced.

The libgmp libraries (libgmp-10.dll and libgmpxx-4.dll) are in the directory "C:/omnet561/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/bin". I think the problem here might be that the software is using the wrong directory to search for the libraries but I'm not sure how to fix such an issue.

Comment: Did you install [libgmp](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp)?

Comment: Yes, libgmp is already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters the same problem, I managed to solve it by using OMNeT++ 5.6.1 and Oversim 20190424 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I built Oversim, I got an error "Could not find gmp.h", to solve that error I installed libgmp3-dev - `apt-get install libgmp3-dev`. If somebody manages to get it to work on Windows 10 or has an idea of how it can be fixed, then please feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path to `libgmp` libraries using `Makefrag`.
Go to OverSim-20190424 `Project Properties`, choose `OMNeT++` | `Makemake` | select `src` | `Options` | `Custom` | `Makefrag` and write:

```
    LIBS += -L/c/libraries/libgmp
```

It is assumed that libgmp libraries (*.dll or *.a) are in `C:\libraries\libgmp`.

**EDIT**
Open `Makefrag` from `oversim-20190424\src\` in a text editor, and then change `LIBS` and `OMNETPP_LIBS` to proper values:

```
LIBS += -L/sw/lib  -L/c/omnet561/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/bin
OMNETPP_LIBS += -lgmp
```

or

```
OMNETPP_LIBS += -lgmp-10
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Makefrag here. There is 'Code fragment to be inserted into Makefile' and 'Other fragment files to include' in Custom tab. I tried adding the directory of libgmp libraries into both but it's still not working. I also tried to change the directory multiple times (C:/, c/, -I$(OMNETPP_ROOT)/, etc.) and not using "LIBS +=" but still I keep getting the same error. I might have done a mistake somewhere because I am not experienced dealing with make files however I feel like I have tried everything so far. I am now getting a new error directory and I updated the question.

Comment: There is Makefrag in Oversim. I have edited my answer and add some ckues how to edit this Makefrag.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. Unfortunately I keep getting the same error and I am sure that I am doing as you instructed me to do properly. When I use "OMNETPP_LIBS += -lgmp-10" I get the following error "C:\omnet561\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin\ld: cannot find -lgmp-10"